# ArcMap: Aligning legend items

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.4

We have to generate hundreds of mxd's and i am currently working on a template. In the template mxd, template legend items will be standard and while changing the source layer path, legend items are aligning to the bottom instead of top. As in the image, "Source A" has all the legend items as that of the template legend and it's getting aligned properly. But as one can see, "Source B" has only one legend and it's getting aligned to the bottom of the legend frame. How to fix this ? Tried with "Legend Properties" and can't able to find the specific option to achieve this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change **Anchor Point** location to **Top left** from legend properties > Size and Position tab, it will align your legend to the top left side of the legend frame.[image]